# Database Connect Error: Centos 6 / Apache 2.4 / Postgres 9.4 / Django 1.9 / mod_wsgi 3.5 / python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache, postgresql

I am trying to get my website up and running. Everything seems to work fine, but when I go to a page with a database write - I get this:

```
[Wed Oct 19 09:53:12.319824 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12411] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Wed Oct 19 09:53:13.001121 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 12411] AH01909: sXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.secureserver.net:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 19 09:53:13.003578 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12411] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 19 09:53:13.003590 2016] [core:notice] [pid 12411] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd'
(XID fsf92m) Database Connect Error: Access denied for user 'leechprotect'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[Wed Oct 19 09:53:17.637487 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12411] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

This line shows that a user "leechprotest" cannot connect:

```
(XID fsf92m) Database Connect Error: Access denied for user 'leechprotect'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

However I don't have a user called leechprotect.  leechportect is a default user on MySQL (im guessing), because MySQL is installed as the default database on my dedicated server.

My Django settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'prelaunch_db',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I already know my database and entire site works on my test server at home.   I think it might be interference with MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT (After disabling leech protection):

```
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:24.000919 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 14754] AH01909: sXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.secureserver.net:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:24.001851 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 14754] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:24.001887 2016] [:notice] [pid 14754] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:24.001892 2016] [:notice] [pid 14754] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.2"; loaded version="1.5.2"
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:24.001897 2016] [:notice] [pid 14754] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.38 "; loaded version="8.38 2015-11-23"
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:24.001900 2016] [:notice] [pid 14754] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:24.001903 2016] [:notice] [pid 14754] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.2"
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:24.001905 2016] [:notice] [pid 14754] ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set SecStatusEngine to On.
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:25.001596 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 14755] AH01909: sXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.secureserver.net:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:25.004276 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14755] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:25.004294 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14755] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -D SSL'
(XID 6jmrjj) Database Connect Error: Access denied for user 'leechprotect'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[Wed Oct 19 11:40:31.847492 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14755] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

EDIT 2:

I found that Apache comes preconfigured on cPanel with a rewrite function:

These lines are in the httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap LeechProtect prg:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/leechprotect
Mutex file:/usr/local/apache/logs rewrite-map
```

I tried to comment out these lines, but cPanel just regenerates the default file. I looked how to edit and I found:

```
[root@sXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX]# /usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update
```

From what I see, anyting written outside the `<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>` tag with be permanently saved when running the above command.

this got rid of the Database error problem.  But I still get a 500 server error.  And all other error log messages are the same.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and PostgreSQL both do not come along with a user called 'leechprotect'. But a google search points out, that this username [is related to cPanel](https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/1152Docs/Leech+Protect) - might be worth reading that to understand whats going on. Afterwards you might consider deactivating it for you project directory.

Comment: My mistake, I contacted my web hosting provider before posting and they told me leechprotect is cPanel.  Also, I disabled it on cPanel.  That doesn't work.  It just gives me a lot of warnings for security in the apache error_log with the same "Database Connect" error.  This only happens for database writes.  And only for database writes through apache requests.  When I write to the database using a custom django management command, it works.

Comment: I made an edit to original post.  This is the new error log for apache after disabling leech protection

Comment: maybe [this topic](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/500-internal-server-error.347151/) helps - it is about the ownbership of the files - there is no hooray in the end, but maybe it solved the error ;) btw - can't you get rid of cPanel at all?

Comment: I like cPanel.  I have a plugin that makes file browsing and editing real easy.  Doing these things through ssh is tedious.....   I think I found the problem.  Apache httpd.conf file on cPanel comes pre-configured with these lines:

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap LeechProtect prg:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/leechprotect
Mutex file:/usr/local/apache/logs rewrite-map

Comment: That didn't come out right, I made another edit in the main post.